# Applications / code security

Tags: javascript, java, python, asp.net, angularjs

I have a 5 applications(programmed in 5 different languages) deployed in one common web server and these applications are written to work on a particular task and create a log file for any action. How can we achieve a security of log file by not being over written by other applications?

Comment: How are all those tags relevant to your question?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you don't trust one application to not clobber the log file of another one, then you have a really serious problem.  `Cos the applications could also do other more harmful things.  If the applications are believed to be insecure or untrustworthy, the *most secure* answer is to not run them at all.

If you are concerned that applications might *accidentally* write to the same log file<sup>1</sup>, just configure them to use different log file names or different log file directories<sup>2</sup>.

If you are simply trying to secure the logging, then one solution is to do your logging via an independent (secure) logging service such as Linux `syslog`.

Another approach is to create separate accounts for running each of the applications, and make sure that you set the file and directory access so that one application doesn't have permission to modify another's log file.

---

<sup>1 - Actually applications *can* safely write to the same file if they all open the logfile in "append" mode.  Log file rotation could be problematic though.</sup>

<sup>2 - You've probably already thought of that.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If your logs are stored in a commong log folder, then a simple solution would be to have proper naming for logs of different applications

e.g.

> pythonApp_log_timestamp
>
> aspNetApp_log_timestamp

This way applications will write to its designated logs and not overwrite other application's log and would work irrespective of your hosting environment linux or windows.

Also you could limit the file size of each of the log file that your applications create, this way you could ensure that applications create new file if specified file size has been reached and not too much data is dumped into a single file, this will help in debugging or verifying the logs later.

I use this method in my application and helps me find the log from specific duration and not searching logs too much.